# CSS Properties: Display vs. Visibility

Tags: css

What is difference between Display vs. Visibility properties?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between visibility:hidden and display:none](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

Comment: @KennyTM: that is assuming OP is asking specifically to compare those respective values of each property.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

The `visibility` property only tells the browser whether to show an element or not. It's either visible (`visible` - you can see it), or invisible (`hidden` - you can't see it).

The `display` property tells the browser **how** to draw and show an element, if at all - whether it should be displayed as an `inline` element (i.e. it flows with text and other inline elements) or a `block`-level element (i.e. it has height and width properties that you can set, it's floatable, etc), or an `inline-block` (i.e. it acts like a block box but is laid inline instead) and some others (`list-item`, `table`, `table-row`, `table-cell`, `flex`, etc).

When you set an element to `display: block` but *also* set `visibility: hidden`, the browser still treats it as a block element, except you just don't see it. Kind of like how you stack a red box on top of an invisible box: the red box looks like it's floating in mid-air when in reality it's sitting on top of a physical box that you can't see.

In other words, this means elements with `display` that isn't `none` will still affect the flow of elements in a page, regardless of whether they are visible or not. Boxes surrounding an element with `display: none` will behave as if that element was never there (although it remains in the DOM).

Comment: .. doesn't display have something to do with the DOM? for example... if you have `display: none;`, then that element is removed from the DOM? or am I totally confused?

Comment: @Hristo: Actually, it doesn't. You can *never* affect an element's position or presence in the DOM with CSS alone.

Comment: @BoltClock... yes, you're right. I've realized that you can never take an element out of the DOM, but only affect *how* it is displayed in regards to the DOM. does that sound more accurate?

Comment: One important thing to note that by using jQuery's hide() method, which internally set display to none, you cannot get the position of this element. WHile using visibility you are able to do it.

Answer (score 28):

#### **`visibility: hidden;`**

- The element won't be painted AND will not receive click/touch, etc. events (differing from `opacity: 0;` in this way), but the space it takes is still occupied.
- Because it's still there for layout purposes, you can measure it without it being visible.
- Changing content will still cause reflow/re-layout of the page.
- `visibility` is inherited, so this means you can make sub-children visible by giving them `visibility: visible;`.

#### **`display: none;`**

- Will make the element not participate in the flow/layout.
- Can (depending on the used browser) kill Flash movies and iframes (which will restart/reload upon showing again), although you can prevent this from happening with iframes.
- The element won't take up any space. For layout purposes, it's like it does not exist.
- Will make some browsers/devices (like the iPad) directly take back memory used by that element, causing small hiccups if you switch between `none` and another value during animations.

#### Extra Notes:

- **Images in `hidden` Content:**

  In all popular browsers, images are still loaded, even though they are within any element with `visibility: hidden;` or `display: none;`.
- **Fonts in `hidden` Content:**

  `-webkit-` browsers (Chrome/Safari) may delay loading custom fonts that are only used in hidden elements, including through `visibility` or `display`. This may cause you to measure elements that are still using a fallback font until the custom font is loaded.

Answer (score 21):

display: none removes the element out of the flow of the html whereas visibility:hidden does not.

Answer (score 3):

`display:none;` will remove the DOM elements visual style / physical space from the DOM, whereas `visibility:hidden;` will not remove the element, but simply hide it. So a `<div>` occupying `300px` of vertical space in your DOM will STILL occupy `300px` of vertical width when set to `visibility:hidden;`, but when set to `display:none;` it's visual styles and the space it occupies are hidden and the space is then "freed" up for lack of a better word.

[EDIT] - It was a while back that I wrote the above, and whether I was not knowledgeable enough or having a bad day, I don't know, but the reality is, the element is NEVER removed from the DOM hierarchy. All block-level `display` 'styles' are completely 'hidden' when using `display:none`, whereas with `visibility:hidden;`, the element itself is hidden, but it still occupies a visual space in the DOM. I hope this clears things up.

Comment: No, `display: none` will *not* remove an element from the DOM. The element is still there, it just isn't *displayed*.