# Performance differences between visibility:hidden and display:none

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance

I want to simplify things in my jQuery Backbone.js web application. One such simplification is the behavior of my menu and dialog widgets.

Previously I created the div boxes of my menus at start and hid them using `display: none; opacity:0;`.   When I needed a menu, I changed its style to `display:block` then used the jQuery ui position utility to position the div box (since elements with `display:none` cannot be positioned) and when it was done, finally changed its style to `opacity:1`.

Now I want to just hide them with `visibility:hidden`, and when I need one, I use the position utility and then change the style to `visibility:visible`.  When I begin using this new approach, I will have around 10 div boxes throughout the web application session that are hidden but occupy space, in contrast to the previous div boxes hidden with `display:none`.

What are the implications of my new approach? Does it effect browser performance in any regard?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not aware of any performance difference between `display:none` and `visibility:hidden` - even if there is, for as little as 10 elements it will be completely negligible.  Your main concern should be, as you say, whether you want the elements to remain within the document flow, in which case `visibility` is a better option as it maintains the box model of the element.

Answer (score 88):

`display:none;` elements are [not in the render tree all](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#Render_tree_construction), so they will perform better at face value.

I doubt you will have any real visible performance problems from this though. If you  need `opacity: 0` or `visibility: hidden` **because of their functionality**, then just use them. If you don't need the functionality, then use `display: none;`

Comment: +1 - very interesting! Do you know which browsers have this render tree optimisation?

Comment: @ChrisFrancis I want to say all but you can never know about IE :D

Comment: Even IE ignores the element if it has "display: none".

Comment: Although it may perform better the first time, if you're toggling `display` fast, you're asking for trouble. Check out the other answers.

Comment: in cases where you have hundreds of elements, such as a tiled map or game, I always remove display attributes in reverse-dom order to prevent reflows on the container!

Comment: For one of my pages with 3D CSS effects and several thousand elements in the DOM, toggling "display" on a large container element caused a lag of almost 500ms on slower mobile devices. Changing the CSS to instead toggle "visibility" eliminated the lag entirely.

Comment: why would display:none perform better at face value? it is not in the render tree, but as soon as you toggle it to display: block or other, it will become a part of the render tree and lead to re layout, while visibility change (theoretically) should not lead to trigger layout

Answer (score 59):

If you are toggling between visible and invisible states via javascript then visibility:hidden should be the better performer. Seeing as it always takes up the same amount of space in both visible and hidden states it won't cause a reflow of the elements below it every time you make it appear of disappear. For display:none you are removing it from the flow of the document and then when you set it to display:block you are rerendering it and pushing everything below that element down, essentially laying all that stuff out again.

But if you are doing something like toggling visible states on button presses then you really should be using what suits your needs rather than what performs better, as the performance differences are negligible in such cases. When you are animating with the dom at around 20 times per second THEN you can worry about the performance of visibility:hidden vs display:none.

Comment: I'd upvote this if you provided sources.  I know that `display:none` causes a reflow whereas `visibility:hidden` does not ... so intuitively I think you are dead-on.  But good answers on SO link to official documentation or deeper explanations; I don't have enough background on this subject to +1 this without sources.

Comment: this article by Nicole Sullivan talks about it. She's generally considered a CSS expert and helped to build CSSLint.  Don't know if this qualifies as a good source but I certainly trust her opinion

http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/27/reflows-repaints-css-performance-making-your-javascript-slow/

Comment: @andywhyisit from this resource it says that changine display to None doesn't cause reflow .. but changing visibility to hidden cause 1x reflow in browsers.
https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/browser-reflow

for me your answer seems correct. but resoursce provided aboove contradicts it. so which one is right ?

Answer (score 52):

`visibility: hidden` does not cause a re-flow on the document, while `display: none` does.

`display: none`: The HTML engine will *completely* ignore the element and its children. The engine will not ignore elements marked with `visibility: hidden`, it will do all the calculations to the element and its children, the exception is that the element will not be rendered to the viewport.

If the values for position and dimensions properties are needed then `visibility: hidden` have to be used and you have to handle the white space in the viewport, usually by wrapping that element inside another one with 0 width and height and 'overflow: hidden'.

`display:none` will remove the element from the document's *normal flow* and set the values for position/height/width to 0 on the element and its children. When the elements `display` property is changed to other value than `none`, it triggers a complete document re-flow, which can be a problem for big documents - and sometimes not-so-big documents being rendered on hardware with limited capabilities.

`display: none` is the natural and logical solution to use when hiding elements on the viewport, `visibility: hidden` should be used as a fallback, where/when needed.

EDIT:
As pointed by @Juan, `display: none` is the choice to go when what you need is to add many elements to the DOM tree. `visibility: hidden` will trigger a re-flow for each element added to the tree, while `display: none` will not.

Comment: This is the real issue with display:none vs. visibility:hidden.  
If you are adding a lot of elements to a DOM, and you add them hidden, then you'll provoke a reflow for each one. 
On the other hand, you can add as many elements as you want with display:none and show them all at once provoking a single reflow.  
The performance taxing action is the the reflow.

Comment: @juanlanus are you suggesting that adding a lot of elements with visibility hidden and changing the visibility to visible for each one of them would provoke a reflow of the document / parent element?  OR are you suggesting that each of these elements would reflow every time there is a reflow triggered on the doc due to some reason, as they are part of the render tree?

Comment: @gaurav5430 a reflow is triggered when a new element is inserted into the DOM. However, if the parent element has display:none, the reflow is not triggered when a new element is added. Visibility:hidden will still trigger a reflow.

Comment: why though, the element is already in the DOM / render tree, we only toggle the visibility from none to visible

Answer (score 7):

Well, the main performance difference between `display: block` and `visibility: hidden` is that if you have a list of, say, 100000 elements, the `visibility: hidden` won't save you from DOM hanging because it doesn't remove elements from DOM.
`visibility: hidden` acts like `opacity: 0` + `pointer-events: none`. `display: none` acts like `Element.remove()`.

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/u2dou58r/10/

Comment: is that because visibility: hidden elements are still aprt of the layout step bit not display:none

Comment: @gaurav5430 well, technically, yes. But it's not quite correct to say that `display: none` elements are not part of the layout, because they can be still reached through JS DOM methods (like `querySelector`). Also, they will still affect `nth-child` CSS pseudo-selectors

Answer (score 3):

From personal experience having just tried both on a simple static page with a form located beneath a "hidden" button, `visibility: hidden` performs flawlessly whereas `display: none` causes clickable buttons to slightly jump upon clicking, as if it tries to show the hidden button for a millisecond.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be somehow related to this question: [CSS Properties: Display vs. Visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475119/css-properties-display-vs-visibility)

I'll just quote the interesting part:

> the element is NEVER removed from the DOM hierarchy. All block level display 'styles' are completely 'hidden' when using display:none, whereas with visibility:hidden; the element itself is hidden but it still occupies a visual space in the DOM.

So there should be no real difference in regard to browser performance, because both versions are still in the DOM hierarchy. These properties only affect *how* an element is displayed in regards to the DOM.

Comment: Just because an element is in DOM hierarchy doesn't mean anything in terms of performance. It depends on how costly it is to render that element and its children on the screen, which can vary arbitrarily.

Comment: both of them are in the DOM tree, but display:none wouldn't be in the render tree

Answer (score 0):

Well, visibility:none still uses the space of the div.
So you could maybe skip the positioning part because its place is already allocated (and by that get a better performance).

But I somehow guess that you need your display:none approach to allocate space correctly when the "show" event is triggered.