# When an element with infinite keyframes animation is hidden via opacity: 0, will PC's resources still be spent on rendering it?

Tags: css, keyframe

I tried to read some w3c specs, but didn't find an answer. Anyone have an insight on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes they will. Opacity 0 is still in the render tree so will use more resourses than say:

- *display: none* which will remove the element from the render tree completely
- *visibility: hidden* which will calculate base properties with width, height, but not actually render it

display is generally better unless reflow becomes an issue in which case visibility will often be quicker.

Please note that there are also lots of similar questions to this like the below which are worth checking out in the future else you'll keep getting down-voted.
[opacity vs visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272360/does-opacity0-have-exactly-the-same-effect-as-visibilityhidden)

[visibility vs display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757016/performance-differences-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)
also bear in mind that opacity: 0 is still in the event and tab models unlike the other 2.