# Which one is best optimized code display:none or visibility:hidden as per the performance?

Tags: html, css

Which one is best optimized code `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` as per the performance?

```
.className{
  display: none;
}
.className{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: The performance difference will be minute, it'll not matter, what matters is that `visibility: hidden` will leave the space occupied, whereas `display: none` will not. If you are so (hyper) conscious about performance, you'll definitely get thousands of improvement areas.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Performance differences between visibility:hidden and display:none](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757016/performance-differences-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

Comment: On initial rendering, `display: none;` will be much faster because the element can simply be ignored for the rendering process. `visibility: hidden:` will be much faster once you make the part visible since the browser has already done all the dimensional calculations before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`visibility:hidden` would be the more efficient as it does not change the flow of the DOM, reducing the amount of redraws.

Switching an element's `display` property would cause greater redrawing as space isn't allocated for the element. This would occur most with stacked elements.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the requirement..if you want to show the element when user interact with the page then `visibility:hidden` can be useful otherwise `display:none` is useful.

`visibility:hidden` takes the space provided to it though it is not visible but `display:none` remove the space and allow other element to take the space.

Answer (score -1):

I think `display:none` is that property which makes tag not to appear on the page but space is not allocated.

And `visibility:hidden` is that property which makes the tag not visible but space is allocated.

Comment: Not my downvote, but the question is specifically about performance. You just describe what the properties do but say nothing about performance.