# set html5 video properties in typescript

Tags: html, typescript

Using [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33762652/does-hiding-an-animated-gif-with-css-conserve-browser-resources), I put this html5 code into a typescript project to play a video automatically and to use a gif as a fallback if html5 video is not supported. However, the `autoplay` and `loop` and `width` and `height` controls create an error in typescript (see below). However, if I remove the `autoplay` `loop` `width` and `height` properties, then I can play the video by accessing the controls in the browser.

Question: How can I set the video to play and loop automatically in typescript?

```
<video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" width="400" height="300">
    <source src={mymp4} type="video/mp4" />
    <img src={fallback.gif} width="400" height="300" />
</video>
```

> Type '{ autoplay: "autoplay"; loop: "loop"; width: "400"; height: "300"; children: Element[]; }' is not assignable to type
>   'DetailedHTMLProps,
>   HTMLVideoElement>'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<video autoPlay loop width="400" height="300">
    <source src={mymp4} type="video/mp4" />
    <img src={fallback.gif} width="400" height="300" />
</video>
```

Notice the case difference on `autoPlay`. Also these are boolean attributes so we can just use the names to set them in jsx.

Comment: ok, I'll try that. was it only the `{ }` brackets that indicated I was using jsx?

Comment: @Leahcim that and the fact you asked about typescript, it's the only way i know of to embed html

Answer (score 1):

i guess that the width and height are on READ ONLY u can't change them

also check this link :

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement