# Make a div keeping its size when hiding elements in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have dynamically created divs. For some tests, I go for 30 divs.

Each div got a button bar at the bottom. I just want to show this bar, when hovering the div container.

When hiding these elements, the div gets smaller / is shrinking down. I want to keep this bigger size, so only the buttons are hidden but the container keeps its size.

When leaving the div, only the buttons should disappear.

```css
#wrapper{
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

#content{
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#wrapper:hover .btn{
  display:block;
}

.btn{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="content">
content
</div>
<div>
<button class="btn">
Button 1
</button>
<button class="btn">
Button 2
</button>
<button class="btn">
Button 3
</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `visibility` instead of `display`

`Visibility` will keep the element space. `display` will remove the space

```css
#wrapper{
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

#content{
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#wrapper:hover .btn{
  visibility:visible;
}

.btn{
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="content">
content
</div>
<div>
<button class="btn">
Button 1
</button>
<button class="btn">
Button 2
</button>
<button class="btn">
Button 3
</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for! But it is really slow, no? I thought it would show/hide instantly

Answer (score 5):

Use `visibility` to control the visibility of the elements. It hides the elements but keeps their occupied area, maintaining the box model, in the page.

```css
#wrapper{
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

#content{
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#wrapper:hover .btn{
  visibility:visible;
}

.btn{
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="content">
content
</div>
<div>
<button class="btn">
Button 1
</button>
<button class="btn">
Button 2
</button>
<button class="btn">
Button 3
</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I needed, but as mentioned above in the comment section, it is really slow, no?

Comment: @peterHasemann Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11757068/2019247). There is no performace impact as far.

Answer (score 1):

you can try both these methods as per your need:

## 1, Only CSS

Using `opacity`.

```css
#wrapper{
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

#content{
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#wrapper:hover .btn{
  opacity:1;
}

.btn{
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="content">
content
</div>
<div>
<button class="btn">
Button 1
</button>
<button class="btn">
Button 2
</button>
<button class="btn">
Button 3
</button>
</div>
</div>
```

## 1, CSS and JQUERY

Uisng the code in your `Q`, only added a class `test-height`

```js
var firstHeight = $('.test-height').height();
$('.test-height').height(firstHeight);
$('.btn').hide();
```

```css
#wrapper{
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

#content{
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#wrapper:hover .btn{
  display:block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="content">
content
</div>
<div class="test-height">
<button class="btn">
Button 1
</button>
<button class="btn">
Button 2
</button>
<button class="btn">
Button 3
</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.ty

Comment: Just dealing with the opacity is significantly faster, yes

Comment: Yep, CSS is much faster. peterHasemann,  I have made some changes in the code please do check it again.