# Do css animations affect performance while invisible

Tags: html, css, browser, css-animations, paint

I'm using React with Material Ui, and encountered a case in which I render an indeterminate Progress Bar when loading a resource. While not showing the progress bar, it still takes up space via `visibility: hidden` css property.

In doing so, the progress bars' css animation also remains active, and while invisible, can still be viewed running with the element inspector.

To disable that, I've changed the mode of the progress bar to determinate(without an animation), like so:

```js
<Fade in={visible}>
    <LinearProgress variant={visible ? 'indeterminate' : 'determinate'} /> 
</Fade>
```

My question is: How does an invisible css animation affect performance and repainting? Does disabling it matters?

EDIT: From what I checked, while it does not cause a repaint, the animation does still run and recalculates style and layout while hidden (at least in chrome and firefox).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Performance differences between visibility:hidden and display:none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757016/performance-differences-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

Comment: I'm afraid not. I'm asking specifically about invisible animation performance

Comment: I have never seen performance issues with css animations, but everything that is happening still is happening regardless of whether the user can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I checked, while it does not cause a repaint, the animation does still run and recalculates style and layout while hidden.

Here is a screenshot of such a performance recording (in Chrome). Note that this
[image: Performance recording]