# jQuery code for simple onClick not working, what am I missing?

Tags: jquery, html, event-handling

I'm fairly new to jQuery, but I thought this would be simple enough to add an `onClick` function.

But for some reason it's not working. I'm thinking it's something little that I am overlooking. Also, I would like the `div-1` to fade in slowly so it doesn't just appear right away.. But for some reason I can't even get the show to work.

Here is my html:

```
    <button id="button-1" style="height: 50px; 
width: 50px; background: red;">Click Me!</button>

    <div id="div-1" style="height: 400px; 
 width: 400px; background: blue; visibility: hidden;"></div>
```

and the jQuery

```
jQuery('#button-1').onClick(){
    jQuery('#div-1').show();
}
```

Here is a fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/2wsHd/

Comment: `jQuery('#button-1').on("click", function() { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong syntax for binding click event, use `display:none` instead of `visibility:hidden`. As show and hide function use display property but not the visibility property.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2wsHd/4/)**

```
jQuery('#button-1').click(function(){
    jQuery('#div-1').show();
});
```

If you want to use visibility property then do not use show and hide rather set property.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2wsHd/10/)**

```
jQuery('#button-1').click(function(){
    document.getElementById('div-1').style.visibility = 'visible';
});
```

You can choose between these two according to your need. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475119/css-properties-display-vs-visibility) will help you in deciding which one to go for.

> The visibility property only tells the browser whether to show an
>   element or not. It's either visible (you can see it), or invisible
>   (hidden - you can't see it).
>
> The display property tells the browser how to draw and show an
>   element, if at all - whether it should be displayed as an inline
>   element (i.e. it flows with text and other inline elements) or a
>   block-level element (i.e. it has height and width properties that you
>   can set, it's floatable, etc), and some others (table, table-row,
>   table-cell, flex, etc), [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475119/css-properties-display-vs-visibility).

Answer (score 1):

Remove `visibility: hidden;` of div id `div-1` and set `display:none`

http://jsfiddle.net/2wsHd/3/

```
$('#button-1').on('click',function(){
    $('#div-1').show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this,**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2wsHd/7/)**

HTML

```
<div id="div-1" style="height: 400px; width: 400px; background: blue; display:none;"></div>
```

javascript

```
$(function(){
    jQuery('#button-1').click(function () {
        jQuery('#div-1').fadeIn("slow")
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

use **display:none;**

```
<button id="button-1" style="height: 50px; width: 50px; background: red;">Click Me!</button>
<div id="div-1" style="height: 400px; width: 400px; background: blue; display: none;"></div>
```

and your JQuery to:

```
$(function() { //on document ready
    $( "#button-1" ).click(function() { //when #button-1 is clicked
        $('#div-1').show(); //show #div-1
    }); //end of click
}); //end of document ready
```

and to make it fade in, change

```
$('#div-1').show();
```

to

```
$('#div-1').fadeIn(1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2wsHd/13/

Answer (score 1):

use click() instead of OnClick() for jquery function.

Use display: none instead of visibility: hidden

Try this:http://jsfiddle.net/2wsHd/14/
http://jsfiddle.net/2wsHd/15/

```
$('#button-1').click(function(){
    $('#div-1').fadeIn('slow');
})
```

OR need to show and hide, by using toggle

```
$('#button-1').click(function(){
    $('#div-1').toggle('slow');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
jQuery('#button-1').click(function(){
    jQuery('#div-1').show();
});
```

To handle the fade in. Use this:

```
jQuery('#button-1').click(function(){
    jQuery('#div-1').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the html ? the also  problem is 'visibility: hidden;' of div need to replace with display:none;