# My image is not becoming visible after commanding it with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, popupwindow

I have hidden images in several different DIV  using embedded css in my head for my html file  but I want to show an specify image using Javascript. For example a pop-up will ask the user which photo will they like to see and to type in what they have choosen and only that photo will pop. So now that I have hidden my image it doesn't want to appear even tho  tell it to become visible in my javascript. What am I doing wrong??? BTW the images have to be assign DIV classes.
here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{background-image:url(http://www.desktopaper.com/wp-content/uploads/simple-stars-background-by-fantmayo-dibs.jpg)
       }
          h1{
             margin-bottom:0;
             background-color:white;
             height:40px;
             width:200px;
             }
          p{
             background-color:#200000; 
             color:white;
             height:250px;
             width:900px;
             float:left;
            }
          #Uhura,#Sulu,#Scotty{
             position:relative;
             background-color:#6E6E6E;
             height:20px;
             width:300px; 
             margin-left:900px;
         display:none;
            }  
     </style>
        </head>
                <body>  
                    <h1><pre>Title Title</pre></h1>
                       <p>text text</p>
                           <div id="Scotty">
                 <img src="images/scotty.jpg" alt="Scotty" width="300" height="300">
            </div>
               <div id="Uhura">
                  <img src="images/uhura.jpg" alt="Uhura" width="300" height="300"> 

                         </div>
                        <div id="Sulu">
                 <img src="images/sulu.jpg" alt="Sulu" width="300" height="300">
                          </div>

           <script>
          var choice;
                    do{        
        choice = window.prompt("Which of these Star Trek members wil you like to see?Enter S for Scotty, U for Uhura, or L for Sulu");
        choice = choice.toUpperCase();
    } while (choice != 'S' && choice != 'U' && choice !='L');

    var member;
   if(choice == 'S'){ 
        member = "Scotty";
        document.getELementById("Scotty").style.visibility='visible';
    }else if(choice == "U"){ 
        member = "Uhura";
        document.getELementById("Uhura").style.visibility='visible';
    }else{
        member= "Sulu";
        document.getELementById("Sulu").style.visibility='visible';
    }
   </script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You have `display: none` in your CSS, but you are setting `visiblity: visible` in your javascript.

Comment: thats because you set the display to none... and not the visibility to hidden.  style.display="block"; instead of style.visibility="hidden";

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are using two different visual display styles.

You use `display: none;` to hide the images, which is okay (this does stop the image from loading though).  Then you try to display them with `visibility: visible`.  The content is still hidden because you didn't change the display style to `block`.

Instead of using `visibility: visible` using `display: block`;

```
if(choice == 'S'){ 
    member = "Scotty";
    document.getElementById("Scotty").style.display ='block';
}else if(choice == "U"){ 
    member = "Uhura";
    document.getElementById("Uhura").style.display = 'block';
}else{
    member= "Sulu";
    document.getElementById("Sulu").style.display = 'block';
}
```

Also, don't know if it was a copy & paste thing, but it is `getElementById` not `getELmentById`.

---

Some [additional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475119/css-properties-display-vs-visibility) info about `display` vs `visibility`.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS you set the div `display:none;`, but in your JavaScript you are setting visibility.

Change this:

```
if(choice == 'S'){ 
    member = "Scotty";
    document.getELementById("Scotty").style.visibility='visible';
}else if(choice == "U"){ 
    member = "Uhura";
    document.getELementById("Uhura").style.visibility='visible';
}else{
    member= "Sulu";
    document.getELementById("Sulu").style.visibility='visible';
}
```

To this:

```
if(choice == 'S'){ 
    member = "Scotty";
    document.getELementById("Scotty").style.display ='block';
}else if(choice == "U"){ 
    member = "Uhura";
    document.getELementById("Uhura").style.display = 'block';
}else{
    member= "Sulu";
    document.getELementById("Sulu").style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems:

1. In your js you're setting the visibility property instead of display
2. Your calling a function `getELementById` (notice the big L?) which doesn't exist. It should be `getElementById`
3. Your `img` elements are missing the closing tag

I corrected all your mistakes and then it works. See:

**http://jsfiddle.net/ZCF76/**

(I also changed the src's links to get some visible results :))