# Ruby on Rails: nested_form_for hidden

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, hidden, nested-forms

I'm trying to figure out how to hide a nested_form on my page. I know how to do hidden fields, but I know that also takes up space on the page still. How would I get it so that the whole form is hidden, and doesn't take up any space?

Form:

```
<%= nested_form_for @game do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for :moves do |move_form| %>
    <div id="table" data-current-player="<%=session[:current_player] %>">
      <%= move_form.hidden_field :position %><br>
      <%= move_form.hidden_field :player, data: {position: move_form.object.position} %>
      <%= move_form.hidden_field :id %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<input type="Submit" style="visibility: hidden">
<% end %>
```

Comment: That sure isn't `HTML`. Please post the corresponding `HTML`.

Comment: try `style="display:none;"`

Comment: Where would I put that? Typically, when I try to insert something into the first line, it comes up with an error.

Comment: try: `<input type="Submit" style="display:none;">` because that's the only thing visible, right?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, I was just trying to figure out how to make the whole form hidden, so I didn't have all of that `hidden_field` hanging out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f.fields_for` is consuming space because you have written break `<br>` inside it. Even though hidden fields doesn't consume space, `f.fields_for` can since it iterates for every associated element(in your case every `move` object).

So in nutshell,

remove `<br>`, css properties for `table` if any which can result in space allocation like `margin, padding`.

As well use  `style="display: none"` over `style="visibility: hidden"` since it can consume space (check [CSS Properties: Display vs. Visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475119/css-properties-display-vs-visibility))

Comment: How do I set an id or class within the nested_form tag so that I can use css?

Comment: you should be able to do so with passing `:class => "some class"` or  `:html_options => {:class => "some class" }`. I have not tested it, but should work.