# How do I navigate to hidden anchors?

Tags: html, css, tags, anchor

I have a hidden element on my page with id `select-box`:

```html
<select style="display:none;" id="select-box">
```

There's a `<label>` at the top of my page:

```html
<label for="select-box">Select box</label>
```

Because the `<select>` is hidden, clicking on the `<label>` has no effect. Is there a way to achieve this, preferably without using any JavaScript?

Comment: Achieve what exactly? If the select is not there, how is the user expected to use it? Also, this is a form element, not an anchor.

Answer (score 3):

The css feature display:none; removes the element from the document.

try:

```
style="visibility:hidden; width:0px"
```

visibility:hidden keeps the element in the dom and also takes up space so I've given a width of 0px to ensure no blank space will remain.

Comment: you may need this .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475119/css-properties-display-vs-visibility

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the fact you are missing the link to your anchor in what you posted, you're right it looks like "display:none" anchors don't work (see: http://jsfiddle.net/odwneeL7/). But you can easily just make an anchor with no content beside what you want to link to, eg:

```
<label for="select-box"><a href="#select-box-anchor">Select box</a></label><br/>

...content...

    <a id="select-box-anchor"></a><select style="display:none;" id="select-box">
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/odwneeL7/1/

Comment: I don't think the OP intended to use an anchor. It sounds like he wanted the label to focus a hidden `<select>` element, which doesn't seem to work. The purpose of focusing a hidden input is unclear. However, your idea of using an anchor seems like a good solution.