# How to toggle visibility of flexbox styled popup with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

So I'd like to have a popup on my page. I would like to style it with flexbox. I'm using scss to style things and I have mixins for flexbox properties.

The issue I came across is that I want to have flexbox properties applied to my popup such as `display: flex` which has it's browser variants:

```
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -moz-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
```

When I try to change css to `display: none` my browser overrides it with `display: -webkit-flex;` so I'm still not hiding my element. I thought about using `visibility` but since jquery uses `.show` and `.hide` with display and not visibility it kind of seemed like a wrong tool.

Should I somehow override the jQuery `.hide()` to change the other display properties as well or maybe create the element each time I want to display it and then delete the html of it after submit?

I have my scss with this overlay-content styling:

```
.overlay-content {
    /* this may or may not be here */
    /* visibility: hidden; */

    @include flex();
    @include flex-direction(column);
    @include flex-justify-content(flex-start);
}
```

And I'd have a code which triggers when I want to display my popup:

```
        $('.overlay-content').css('visibility: visible;');
        $('.overlay-bg').css('visibility: visible;');
```

Is it okay to use the visibility css property or should I always use the display property to change the visibility of the element?

What bothers me is that this way I can't use the cool `jquery.hide()` options for cool user experience

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include tthe shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I've edited in hopes of better clarification

Comment: http://codepen.io/snuuve/pen/LVodrm It's working as it's should.  Also read this about `Display` vs `VIsibility` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475119/css-properties-display-vs-visibility .

Comment: Indeed `.hide` seesm to work just fine. If you show us the implemenation where it *doesn't* work (in a suitable demo). we can see what might be causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same issue and solution I came up with may not be the most elegant but it does the job.

I simply called `.hide()` in the initialization code of the component. jQuery adds inline `display: none` to the element, and subsequent call to `.toggle()` removes it, so specified in the stylesheet `display: flex` comes into play.