# Set opacity with js or close modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to "close" a modal window. It's a wordpress template and it's ugly... 
I have a div :

```
<div class="modal">
    <section style="position:relative;z-index:10;">
        <div style="margin-bottom: -50px; margin-right: 50px; text-align: right;">
            <img src="./wp-content/img.png" alt="Close">
        </div>
        <p><img src="./wp-content/img2.png" alt="test"></p>
    </section>
</div>
```

And when the img with `alt="Close"` is clicked, I would like to close or set the opacity of all the div.modal at 0. Is it possible with JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery

```
$('img[alt*=Close]').click(function() {
    $('.modal').hide();
});
```

JS

```
var img = document.querySelector('img[alt*=Close]'),
       modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
img.addEventListener('click', function() {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
});
```

Comment: Thanks it's exactly what I needed, with the 'alt' selector. Thanks!

Comment: Just to add to this, `display : none` and `visibility : hidden` are different. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475119/css-properties-display-vs-visibility

Answer (score 1):

*when the img with `alt="Close"` is clicked, I would like to close or set the `opacity` of all the `div.modal` at 0.*

Absolutely!

First i want to mention that there is some attribute selectors which are now officially available in css3, so that can be used as a jQuery selector like:

```
$('body').on('click', 'img[alt="Close"]', function(e){
    $(this).closest('.modal').fadeOut(); // to fade out the entire div.
    // $(this).closest('.modal').hide(); // hide will hide the modal
});
```

If your modal is dynamically created then you have to follow the technique of event delegation, which has the syntax like:

```
$(staticParent).on(event, selector, callback);
```

Comment: A little question... When a modal window is created, the website URL becomes : http://url.com/#idModal  . And if I hide it, the URL keeps #idModal even with `window.location`. I can't open an other modal window. Is there any way to recover the base url after hidding the modal?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for click events on the img div with:

```
document.querySelector("img[alt=Close]").addEventListener("click", yourHandler);
```

**However**, accessing an image using its `alt` attributes looks like a terrible idea. `alt` is to display infotip and accessibility message for the user, not to identify a DOM element.
It would much better if you can give this image an id or a class:

```
document.getElementById("yourImgId").addEventListener("click", yourHandler);
```

Then:

```
var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");

function yourHandler(){
   modal.style.opacity = 0;
}
```

or

```
function yourHandler(){
   modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

A last solution can be to define the style properties in a stylesheet like:

```
.modal.disabled {
    display: none;
}
```

And then add the class to `modal` to disable it.

```
function yourHandler(){
    modal.classList.add("disabled");
}
```

This last solution is more flexible and easier to maintain as it separates the logic to the style.

Answer (score 0):

Yep! Just set thee css property `opacity`

`$(".modal").css({ opacity: 0.5 });`

Comment: Thanks! On a click event on the img?

Comment: Yep! If thats what you want.