# Recover base url after modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery

After my last question : [Set opacity with js or close modal window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32985773/set-opacity-with-js-or-close-modal-window)

The function works, the modal window is well hidden. But when this modal window is created, the website URL becomes : http://url.com/#idModal

If the div is hidden, the URL stays with #idModal and I can't open an other modal window. 
Is there any way to recover the base URL? I tried with `window.location` but it reloads the page with #idModal...

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);
```

It will remove hashtag part from current URI.

[Here](http://caniuse.com/#search=pushstate) you can see the browser support of History API.

Comment: Recent browsers. Thanks it works, I can't open a new modal window but the url is clean. To open a new window I reload the page after cleaning the URL

Comment: Why you can't open new modal window?