# I need h2 elements to close at small screen sizes

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm redesigning my websites, adding Bootstrap and jQuery. Each section of my articles begins with code that looks like this:

```
<section id="introduction"><h2 class="h2Article" id="a1" data-    toggle="collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#b1"><span class="Article"><span class="label label-primary"><small><span class="only-collapsed glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span><span class="only-expanded glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span></small> Introduction</span></span></h2>
  <div class="divArticle collapse in article collapse in article" id="b1">
```

When I preview a page, I can click on a heading (h2) to make it close. Clicking on it a second time opens it again.

It works perfect, but I'd like to modify it so that when someone views the page in a mobile device, everything is CLOSED by default. The user would then choose a particular h2 heading and click on it to read that section.

Does anyone know how I can do that?

The simplest way would be to presumably create some kind of style, like this:

```
@media all and (max-width: 450px) {    
.h2Article { close; } 
}
```

But I don't know what CSS command to replace "close" with. Of course, I need a style that would allow the visitor to both close and open it by clicking on the header.

If it can't be done this way, can you suggest another strategy? I was going to use Wikipedia as an example, because its mobile pages used to be set up like this, but I just discovered that they changed it.

Comment: You need to alter the jqery probably, not the CSS. You haven't posted any relative css or jquery.. so it's difficult to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to use CSS property display/visibility. Change  the display to none for display or hidden for visibility.

```
.h2Article { 
   diplay: none;
}

or
.h2Article { 
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

When it is clicked, using Jquery/Javascript to change the property from none to block or hidden to visible. For comparison of the properties, you may refer to [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475119/css-properties-display-vs-visibility)

I hope this help. thankyou

---

This is screenshot from the wikipedia site. each click trigger the class to change the CSS property display from none to block.

[image: Screenshot from wikipedia site]

Comment: Sorry, I guess I did a poor job of explaining what I'm trying to do. The header (h2) should actually ALWAYS be visible. I just want to make the text inside <div class="divArticle collapse invisible by default in small screens. The text should then appear when someone clicks on the header.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom Wikipedia also using property display for the content. You may use the jQuery to help you [add](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [remove] (https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) the class from the content tag (your <span> inside the <h2> tag).
For your <h2> tag, you may use jQuery to bind the click action to <h2> tag so it can trigger the add/remove class for your content.

Answer (score 0):

code snippet :

```js
function f(elem) {
  if ($(elem).parent().find(".divArticle").is(":visible"))
    $(elem).parent().find(".divArticle").css("display", "none");
  else
    $(elem).parent().find(".divArticle").css("display", "block");
}
```

```css
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  .divArticle {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h2 onclick="f(this)">hello</h2>
  <div class="divArticle">I'm an article</div>
</div>
```

---

for the CSS, this will hide your div on small screen :

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {    
    .divArticle { display : none; } 
}
```

With a Jquery that call something like that :

```
$(element).is(":visible");
```

And use this to switch between you displayed/hidden