# Check visibility before proceeding

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to do a callback for the below?

```
$('.element').css("visibility","visible");
```

I came across this but seems like there are issues using this in chrome.

```
$('.element').css("visibility","visible").promise().done(function(){
    alert( 'done! start stuff...' );
});
```

Basically I'm looking for a way to confirm that the `$('.element')` is visible before proceeding to the next line.

Comment: `jQuery.css` is a synchronous, Why do you need `promise` for that ?

Answer (score 1):

Setting an element to be visible is synchronous so there is no reason or purpose to using a promise with that.  There is nothing to wait for that to take effect.

```
$('.element').css("visibility","visible");
console.log($('.element').css("visibility"));   // will show "visible" immediately
```

If, on the other hand, you want to wait for a repaint so the item is actually drawn on the screen, that is a different story.  You will have to either force a repaint (which is a tricky non-standard thing to do in browsers these days as they try to avoid synchronous repaints) or you will have to use a slight delay with `setTimeout()` which allows a repaint to happen.

Answer (score 0):

For making an element visible, try `display:block` or `display:inline-block` (and a bunch of other display properties other than `display:hidden`).

Here is a [difference between display and visibility properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475119/css-properties-display-vs-visibility).

Also, making an element `visible` doesn't guarantee that it is visible to user since it could be child of `hidden parent element`. You can use [visible selector](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) of jquery to confirm the same.

```
$('.element').css("display","block");

if ( $('.element').is( ":visible" )
{

}
```