# Priority order of visibility and display in CSS

Tags: html, css

I know that `display: none` removes the element from the page while `visibility: hidden` hides the element but preserves the space.

My question is, is it a good idea to use the two styles together on an element and if so, what is the priority order of the two when used together?

My use case is like so:

- When `shouldRemoveElement = true`, Irrespective of
  `shouldHideElement` the div should be removed from the page.
- When `shouldRemoveElement = false`, the div should respect the
  `visibility` style based on the `shouldHideElement` value.

While this works as expected I'm wondering if it could cause any unexpected side effects.

sample code:

```
<div className="field-container count-field"
        style={{ display: shouldRemoveElement ? 'none' : true, visibility: shouldHideElement ? 'hidden' : 'visible' }}>
      <customComponent>..</customComponent>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no unexpected side effects of using `display: none` with `visibility: hidden`, if that's what you're asking. Since `display: none` removes the element's box from the layout, `visibility` isn't going to have any effect no matter what value you set it to, because there's nothing left to show or hide.

Once you do return an element to the layout by changing its `display` property from `none`, whatever value it had for `visibility` at the time will resume effect, and the element will continue to affect its surrounding layout by its now-generated box.

See also: [CSS Properties: Display vs. Visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475119/css-properties-display-vs-visibility/3475130#3475130)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there are no priority level at all. Both are use for different case. You can't override one by another, `display: none` can't override by using `visibility: visible`.

Actually answer is present in your question ("I know that display: none removes the element from the page while visibility: hidden hides the element but preserves the space").

`display` and `visibility` both are used for different purpose only common feature is both are hide the element from user eye but both keep the element in DOM structure. So in both case you can access the element as a object from DOM tree. That's why we can't say like that `display: none` remove the element.

We can hide element by another way using `opacity: 0` but difference with `display` and `visibility` is both are kept away element from `mouse` `events` where `opacity` give us chance to apply all of the `mouse events` suppose `hover`, `mousedown`, `mouseup`, `click` etc.

Answer (score 0):

whichever CSS is written last will be applicable unless it is defined as `!important`, `display` and `visibility` are two different CSS property you can't priorities between them